# Flutter - Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, dart

After updating to Catalina 10.15.4 beta with Xcode 13.4 beta, which also updated Simulator to 13.4 (921.4).

The application compiles and runs correctly on a physically attached device, but no simulators of any devices can pass this stage.

I got the errors

> Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS Simulator.

or

> Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: all the answers didn't work, kidly find this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306886/348589

Answer (score 63):

Xcode 11.4 changed the way frameworks are linked and embedded, and you may experience issues switching between iOS devices and simulators. Flutter v1.15.3 and later will automatically migrate your Xcode project.

To get unstuck, follow the instructions below;

- **Quick fix** (make your simulator work)

`rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework`

- **[Official](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration) recommended Steps to migrate manually**

  1. From the Flutter app directory, open ios/Runner.xcworkspace in
     Xcode.
  2. In the Navigator pane, locate the Flutter group and remove App.framework and Flutter.framework.
     [image]
  3. In the Runner target build settings Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries confirm App.framework and Flutter.framework are no longer present. Also confirm in Build Phases > Embed Frameworks.

[image]

4. Change the Runner target build settings Build Phases > Thin Binary script as follows:

   > /bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh"
   >   embed
   >
   > /bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh"
   >   thin

[image]

5. In the Runner target **Build Settings > Other Linker Flags**

   (OTHER_LDFLAGS) add $(inherited) -framework Flutter

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Works like charm !

Comment: One thing to notice here in the first step - remove reference

Answer (score 13):

1. Select your Target from "TARGETS"
2. Select 'Build Settings'
3. Under 'Build Options' -> Set 'Validate Workspace' To 'YES'
4. After successfully building, set it back to 'NO'

**Reason** :
"In Xcode 12+, the default option for Validate Workspace is internally not set. We need to set it manually to avoid this kind of error. There is no problem in setting back to the default 'NO' option.

Comment: worked for Mapbox as well when I migrated to Xcode 12.4

Comment: more clear is here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306886/348589

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 11.4 changed the way frameworks are linked and embedded, which is causing issues switching between iOS devices and simulators.

Please follow [official guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration) on how to migrate your project.

Comment: After following the official guide, my app still did not load on my physical device. It was only after following the guide, running `flutter clean` several times, deleting `Pods/` folder and `Podfile.lock`, then reinstalling using `pod install` in the ios folder that it finally worked.

Answer (score 3):

After several days trying to find a solution to test the Flutter app on iOS device, I finally found this:

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios
```

-Open xCode and run app on your device.

Comment: Still doesnt work for me. does the same thing when i try to run the `flutter build ios`

Comment: Follow this link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration

Answer (score 3):

Updated to Xcode 11.4. Ios 13.4, Iphone X. App just fetches data using API. 
App started on white screen and then finally crashes, both on simulator and device.

I followed the offical guide (I also `rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework`)
[flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration).
I ran several times `flutter clean`

I also tried deleting Pods/ folder and Podfile.lock, then reinstalling using `pod install` in the ios folder.

As I am using async data I also added as 1st line in main()

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

No help, app did not started either simulator.

Then I removed `ios/` and `android/` folders. After that in project folder I ran command `flutter create .` that regenerates mentioned folders.

After this my app started fine both on simulator and on device.
I hope this would be help to others.  NOTE!! if you have done any modifications manually to those folders please take backup or commit beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the solution on the official website of flutter but it didn't work for me, so I found a temporary solution which worked for me, but it took me some hard works:
Here is my example with project stuck_framework which is a fresh new project (first time run on the simulator)

1. I created 2 folders inside flutter project called
   "ios_simulator" and "ios_real_device".
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e96Ut.jpg)
2. Now my first build was for the simulator, then I want to switch to a real device, I will move ios folder inside Flutter project to the "ios_simulator"
3. I open the project with visual studio code and run "flutter create ." and now I will choose a real device to rebuild the project ( if your simulator is online, please quit ). 
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvYJ0.png)
4. Now I wait for the build finish and run on the real device without any errors. Now I have 2 ios project 1 for simulators and one for real devices.
5. Next time when I want to run on the simulator again, I just remove the current ios folder and copy the ios folder which I placed on "ios_simulator" back out to flutter project folder. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Manually upgrading flutter to version 1.15 solve this issue as well. Running `flutter version v1.15.17` helped me.

Also, you can switch to `beta` or `dev` channels by running `flutter channel` command but be sure you check your code against all BC changes...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it works only simulator(debug). if you want to deploy your app on the app store(release) i highly recommend you to upgrade flutter version using

```
flutter version v1.15.17
```

otherwise you would encounter crashed app with white screen.

just upgrade flutter version then all things work well

Comment: `1.15.17` is not on the Stable channel yet.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the **Xcode 11.4** and can be resolved by **Removing / Re-Embedding** frameworks and adding a new **Run Script Phase**.

- Under **General** -> "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content"

  - Delete the frameworks that are causing errors.
  - After deleting, re-embed the frameworks in the same location.
- Under **Build Phases** add a new run script phase.

  - Select the "+" button in the "Build Phases" pane to create a "New Run Script Phase".
  - Confirm the script is the bottommost build phase, and configure its fields.

    - The **Shell** text field should read `/bin/sh` (which is the default value).
    - In the text-input area, enter the shell command `rm -r "FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY/YOUR_FRAMEWORK.framework/"`

[image: Run Script Phase]

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions here worked for me. In my case, the problem was fixed by searching my project for ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH and changing them all to YES. I found my solution here:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/656509