# Flutter - Building for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

When I run the flutter app on an iOS Simulator:

`Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS.`

Answer (score 0):

`rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework`

Found this works. Credit to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60921761/892669) and @loïc-fonkam