# I deleted App.framework and flutter.framework from X-Code. Any help getting them back?

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos-catalina

I had this error trying to run my flutter app on my iPhone:

'Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded framework 'App.framework' was built for iOS Simulator.'

And in trying to follow the instructions from flutter's documentation at https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration, I deleted App.framework and flutter.framework from the libraries. Now I can't find them on the list at 'Link binaries with libraries'.

Can I get any help getting them back?

Comment: Try `flutter create .` in your project root directory

Comment: Try ```flutter build ios```

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by **Xcode 11.4**

I've answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802086/7536965

Flutter has also released new documentation that will also aid you in resolving this issue: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration