# Nativescript: Error Building for iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, nativescript, ios-simulator

I have followed the complete install guide for nativescript on a Mac (Big Sur). Also when running tns doctor everything seems fine. However, when i'am running tns build ios or tns run ios i get the following error:

**error: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'TNSWidgets.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. (in target 'projectapp' from project 'projectapp').**

Could someone please tell me how  to fix this. I installed nativescript 7.0.11 and
x-code 12.3

Answer (score 8):

Yesterday with the Xcode update (12.3) I've got the same error, after seeing a lot of posts about this error the solution from [Niko Dovidija](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6047376/niko-dovidija) IS THE CORRECT ONE.

My environment:

1. Xcode 12.3
2. iOS platform 6.5.3
3. Nativescript  6.7.8

In order to build the application in CLI update **build.xconfig** in iOS platform and add this line:

VALIDATE_WORKSPACE = YES

Posts about "similar" errors and didn't work for me.

1. [Building for iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267897/building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-framework-framework-was-built)
2. [Building for iOS simulator 'AFNetworking.framework'](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/4618)

Answer (score 5):

So I just updated Xcode to 12.3 today, using nativescript 7.0.11 in my project and I got a simular issue. What worked for me was:

1. Open the platforms/ios folder using Xcode
2. Select "**yourprojectname.xcodeproj**" from the list
3. Select **yourprojectname** from the Targets
4. Expand *Build Options* and find *Validate Workspace*
5. Change to Yes
6. Rebuild the project

After that, I got a successful build.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I also needed to run `ns platform clean ios` command in order to make the build work after updating my Xcode to 12.3