# Missing required architecture x86_64 Error in Swift Project?

Tags: ios, swift, zendesk

I've been trying to add Zendesk to my swift project and have been trying to follow these steps:

https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/ios_support_sdk/sdk_add#adding-the-sdk-with-cocoapods

I have added the pod using this command: `pod 'ZendeskSupportSDK'`

and also added this to my project's `Build Phases`:

```
bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/SupportSDK.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"
```

However, when I try to run my project, I get this error:

```
The linked framework 'project-name.framework' is missing one or more architectures required by this target: x86_64.
```

Have been trying to find a solution for this for hours now and still haven't found anything that works for me!

I found a few similar answers on Stackoverflow and google and tried them but none of them worked!

is there something specific that I need to do to make this work and be able to use the above pod?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way I can check if this is your specific case, but I had a similar error recently, related to Xcode 12.3 and 12.4, architectures, and embedded frameworks.

What solved it for me was following the [answers described in this StackOverflow post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267897/building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-framework-framework-was-built)

Try setting Validate Workspace to Yes in the Build Settings tab of your project.

Comment: This removes the error but produces another error which is: Could not find module 'SCLAlertView' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64, arm64-apple-ios-simulator. SCLAlertView' is another pod that I'm using. this error won't show up if I don't set Validate Workspace to Yes!

Comment: Okay, that is not something I had in my project once I set my Validate Workspace setting to yes. What does your `VALID_ARCHS` build setting look like? You can find it at the bottom of your project's Build Settings. In your case, it might look like this: `VALID_ARCHS = arm64, arm64e`. If that is your case, try adding `x86_64`. It should look like this: `VALID_ARCHS = arm64, arm64e, x86_64`.

Comment: I thought VALID_ARCHS was removed?! I don't have that at all.