# Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded item 'WowzaGoCoderSDK' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, wowza

I'm using Wowza's sample iOS code and trying to build but it's giving me nightmare in getting it build let alone run. How to fix this issue?

```
Building for iOS, but the linked and embedded item 'WowzaGoCoderSDK' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator.
```

Comment: did you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65306886/5464087 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked framework '\*\*\*\*.framework' was built for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267897/building-for-ios-simulator-but-the-linked-framework-framework-was-built)

Comment: I've already seen that. Setting that to YES gives another error - SettingsViewModel.h:10:9: 'WowzaGoCoderSDK/WowzaGoCoderSDK.h' file not found